# How to ignore filename convention with Jest testPathIgnorePatterns (React, Jest, Regex)

Tags: regex, reactjs, jestjs

Im trying to set up a convention to ignore any test that follows a pattern. The filename would look like this if you wanted jest to ignore it during npm test.

`DISABLED.MyComponent.test.js`

trying to use testPathIgnorePatterns

`testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/src/**/DISABLED.{*}.js'],`

The error is either it is still being run, or it throws a error that the regex is invalid.

Comment: As the name suggests this property is only for ignoring paths

Comment: @Teneff any suggestion for a different property to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jest uses [glob patterns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) to match the test files, so prefixing the default entries in [the `testMatch` configuration](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) with `!(DISABLED.)` should do the job.

**`package.json`**

```
{
  // ... rest of the package
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "**/__tests__/**/!(DISABLED.)*.[jt]s?(x)",
      "**/!(DISABLED.)?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
    ]
  }
}
```

---

**Side note:** You can also "disable" the test file by renaming the main `describe` block to `xdescribe` or `describe.skip`, which would give visibility that there are skipped tests instead of completely ignore the file

```
Test Suites: 1 skipped, 11 passed, 11 of 12 total
Tests:       2 skipped, 112 passed, 114 total
```

Comment: The disable syntax still wouldn't work with those globs, but I like your side note a lot better, the visibility is important. Thanks @Teneff

Answer (score 8):

The other answers here are helpful but miss the core fact:

**`testPathIgnorePatterns` *can* be used to ignore your filenames. The problem is that [`testPathIgnorePatterns` takes a RegExp](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring), not a glob as you've specified.**

The default setting for `testPathIgnorePatterns` is `"/node_modules/"`, so it's probably useful to include it as well.

As an example, to ignore end to end tests that have an "e2e-" prefix, you could use:

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/e2e-"
]
```

In your specific case, this would be something like the following (note how the `.` is escaped in `/DISABLED\\.`):

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "/DISABLED\\."
]
```

Comment: should be `"/DISABLED\\."`.  Otherwise `\.` would be processed as Javascript into `.` first, before being processed by Jest.

Answer (score 2):

`testPathIgnorePatterns` is an array of regex patterns that ignores any **path** that matches the listed expressions and should contain the default `"/node_modules/"` as well. While it is not intended you may as well use testPathIgnorePatterns to exclude specific files:

So, your best bet would be to move the ignored test to s separate folder, e.g.

```
"jest": {
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
    "/node_modules/",
    "<rootDir>/ignore/this/path/" 
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but doesn't quite fit my use case. I will keep it in mind though. Really hoping I can disable based on some-type of naming convention, but this will be my backup plan.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it will not help you ignoring specific files". `testPathIgnorePatterns` considers the full path **including** the filename.

Comment: @rinogo I a not sure either. It has been a while. I think I remove that sentence since it is misleading. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So @Teneff 's answer nearly worked for me. I had to move the `!` to the front of the statement to get it to work. Hope this helps someone else too! I am using Next.JS 12.

```
testMatch: [
    '**/*.test.{ts,tsx}',
    '!**/__tests__/**/(DISABLED.)*.[jt]s?(x)',
    '!**/(DISABLED.)?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)',
]
```

Comment: react apps don't support testPathIgnorePatterns unless you eject.  This is a great solution for that case.